# Will Ana DPS drop if she keeps shooting the same target?

Tags: overwatch

Ana does damage over time rather than instant damage.

If she attacks the same target, will her DPS drop?

Answer (score 9):

Ana's damage-over-time ticks are really fast, faster than her rate of fire.

Unless she's targeted by her own ult, her over time damage will have resolved before she could fire another round.

Comment: What would happen if she is nanoboosted? AFAIK she can auto-boost herself on FFA.

Comment: I don't know, it would require some tests, same for no limits: do multiple Ana's shots on the same target cumulate?